# C++Builder App Default Icon Should Not Appear in Explorer

Tags: icons, c++builder

I am creating a small, self-contained app (no dynamic RTL or runtime packages) and have assigned an icon (.ico) file. The icon appears in the corner of the main form and on the taskbar. But the default C++Builder 11.1 icon appears in Explorer. How can I correct the icon seen in Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

The icon displayed on the Form's window, and on the Taskbar, is controlled by the [`TForm::Icon`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.Icon) property, which you can set at design-time using the Object Inspector.

The icon displayed in Windows Explorer is controlled by the icon specified in the [`Project > Options > Application > Icons`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Application_Options) configuration:

> Specify an icon file (.ico) to be inserted into the output file. **The application icon that is displayed on this dialog box is displayed in Windows Explorer**, next to the output file name.

Comment: Thank you, Remy, as always. I had already used the Project > Options > Application > Icons process to set up the icon before I posted my question. I ultimately resolved the problem by migrating (not a simple copy-and-paste) the project to a new directory. So, it appears that one of the original project files was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by migrating (not a simple copy-and-paste) the project to a new directory. So, it appears that one of the original project files was causing the problem.